# No space left on device - wrong size

Tags: unix, freebsd, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization

I'm running an FreeBSD dedicated server. I am getting messages that I have ran out of space on the device. `df -h` is saying that I have no space left but `du -sh /*` doesn't even show the directiories with a size that the `df -h` is showing.

`df -h` output:

```
# df -h
Filesystem     Size    Used   Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/ad4s1a     18G     17G   -2.9M   100%    /
devfs          1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /dev
/dev/ad4s1b    1.8T    379G    1.2T    23%    /home
linprocfs      4.0k    4.0k      0B   100%    /usr/compat/linux/proc
procfs         4.0k    4.0k      0B   100%    /proc
devfs          1.0k    1.0k      0B   100%    /var/named/dev
```

Its showing that / partition is full, however `du -sh` don't even show that huge directories (not even a 4GB is being taken):

```
# du -sh /*
8.0k    /COPYRIGHT
1.2M    /bin
416M    /boot
  0B    /compat
2.5k    /dev
  2M    /etc
8.4M    /lib
3.7M    /libexec
2.0k    /media
2.0k    /mnt
  0B    /proc
5.1M    /rescue
3.7M    /root
5.8M    /sbin
  0B    /sys
2.9M    /tmp
2.5G    /usr
662M    /var
```

---

Additional, `df -i` output:

```
# df -i
Filesystem   1K-blocks      Used      Avail Capacity iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/ad4s1a   19834638  18247768        100   100%  253233   2313933   10%   /
devfs                1         1          0   100%       0         0  100%   /dev
/dev/ad4s1b 1871693806 397838408 1324119894    23%   87535 241862159    0%   /home
linprocfs            4         4          0   100%       1         0  100%   /usr/compat/linux/proc
procfs               4         4          0   100%       1         0  100%   /proc
devfs                1         1          0   100%       0         0  100%   /var/named/dev
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Pay attention, `du -sh /*` doesn't show the size of the hidden folders and files in root folder. you may have /.snap or like that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. perhaps, you clean up `apache`'s logs recently? if so, try to restart `apache` after that as well and you should regain your space back.
2. run `fsck` as your filesystem may be corrupted.

---

few ways to clean up your logs:

- setup logrorate (better way).
- `echo > $FILE` (dirty way).

Comment: Oh. I was cleaning up `nginx` logs to be exact... Restarted the service and it worked, didn't know its locking the space its using :) Thank you.